# How to insert a block with custom properties using AutoLISP?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I'm trying to insert blocks with custom properties. How do I set those variables?

Within the Deciduous block there is a custom property called "visibility" with various different styles (Visibility 1, Visibility 2, Visibility 3, ...).

For instance, how would I insert the Deciduous block with Visibility 3.

```
(DEFUN C:TREE ( / DECIDUOUS CONIFER SHRUBMEDIUM SHRUBSMALL)
  (INITGET 1 "DECIDUOUS CONIFER SHRUBMEDIUM SHRUBSMALL")
  (OR
    (SETQ RETKWORD (GETKWORD "\nSpecify tree type: [DECIDUOUS/CONIFER/SHRUBMEDIUM/SHRUBSMALL]:"))
    (SETQ RETKWORD "DECIDUOUS")
    )
  (IF (= RETKWORD "DECIDUOUS")
    (PROGN
      (SETQ OLDLAYER (GETVAR "CLAYER"))
      (SETQ FLAG (TBLSEARCH "LAYER" "L-PLNT-DECD"))
      (IF FLAG
    (SETVAR "CLAYER" "L-PLNT-DECD")
    )
      (INITGET 1 "Visibility1 Visibility2 Visibility3")
      (OR
    (SETQ CMDKWORD (GETKWORD "\nPick a command: [Visibility1/Visibility2/Visibility3]:"))
    )
      (IF (= CMDKWORD "Visibility3")
    (PROGN
      (COMMAND "INSERT"
           "TT-L-TREE-DECIDUOUS"
           )
      )
    )
      (PRINC)
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question ultimately depends on whether or not you require the *visual preview* of the inserted block reference, as afforded by the AutoCAD `INSERT` command.

Since the standard AutoCAD `INSERT` command does not prompt for dynamic block parameter values during block insertion, you'll need to insert the block and then manipulate the visibility state using the ActiveX properties & methods of the inserted dynamic block reference, specifically, using the [`getdynamicblockproperties`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-16C8768B-2533-45FF-9CFF-FF864AC78202-htm.html) method.

---

#### *If the visual preview of the inserted block is NOT required...*

...then you can forego the `INSERT` command entirely, and use the [`insertblock`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-17F86FDD-B7FC-4F43-9F16-B4958F73A66D-htm.html) method of the target container object (modelspace/paperspace/block definition), which will return a block reference vla-object.

Here is a basic example demonstrating how to use the [`insertblock`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-17F86FDD-B7FC-4F43-9F16-B4958F73A66D-htm.html) method:

```lisp
(defun c:test ( / dwg ins )
    (if
        (and
            (setq dwg (getfiled "Select Block" "" "dwg" 16))
            (setq ins (getpoint "\nSpecify insertion point: "))
        )
        (vla-insertblock
            (vlax-get-property
                (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))
                (if (= 1 (getvar 'cvport))
                    'paperspace
                    'modelspace
                )
            )
            (vlax-3D-point (trans ins 1 0))
            dwg
            1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
(vl-load-com) (princ)
```

This method will return a block reference vla-object, whose dynamic block properties you can then manipulate using the array of dynamic block properties returned by the [`getdynamicblockproperties`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-16C8768B-2533-45FF-9CFF-FF864AC78202-htm.html) method.

Since you are looking to modify the Visibility State in particular, you may wish to consider the following set of functions that I have developed as part of my [dynamic block library](http://lee-mac.com/dynamicblockfunctions.html) to modify the visibility state of a supplied block reference object:

```lisp
;; Set Dynamic Block Visibility State  -  Lee Mac
;; Sets the Visibility Parameter of a Dynamic Block (if present) to a specific value (if allowed)
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; val - [str] Visibility State Parameter value
;; Returns: [str] New value of Visibility Parameter, else nil

(defun LM:SetVisibilityState ( blk val / vis )
    (if
        (and
            (setq vis (LM:getvisibilityparametername blk))
            (member (strcase val) (mapcar 'strcase (LM:getdynpropallowedvalues blk vis)))
        )
        (LM:setdynpropvalue blk vis val)
    )
)

;; Get Visibility Parameter Name  -  Lee Mac
;; Returns the name of the Visibility Parameter of a Dynamic Block (if present)
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; Returns: [str] Name of Visibility Parameter, else nil

(defun LM:getvisibilityparametername ( blk / vis )  
    (if
        (and
            (vlax-property-available-p blk 'effectivename)
            (setq blk
                (vla-item
                    (vla-get-blocks (vla-get-document blk))
                    (vla-get-effectivename blk)
                )
            )
            (= :vlax-true (vla-get-isdynamicblock blk))
            (= :vlax-true (vla-get-hasextensiondictionary blk))
            (setq vis
                (vl-some
                   '(lambda ( pair )
                        (if
                            (and
                                (= 360 (car pair))
                                (= "BLOCKVISIBILITYPARAMETER" (cdr (assoc 0 (entget (cdr pair)))))
                            )
                            (cdr pair)
                        )
                    )
                    (dictsearch
                        (vlax-vla-object->ename (vla-getextensiondictionary blk))
                        "ACAD_ENHANCEDBLOCK"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        (cdr (assoc 301 (entget vis)))
    )
)

;; Get Dynamic Block Property Allowed Values  -  Lee Mac
;; Returns the allowed values for a specific Dynamic Block property.
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; prp - [str] Dynamic Block property name (case-insensitive)
;; Returns: [lst] List of allowed values for property, else nil if no restrictions

(defun LM:getdynpropallowedvalues ( blk prp )
    (setq prp (strcase prp))
    (vl-some '(lambda ( x ) (if (= prp (strcase (vla-get-propertyname x))) (vlax-get x 'allowedvalues)))
        (vlax-invoke blk 'getdynamicblockproperties)
    )
)

;; Set Dynamic Block Property Value  -  Lee Mac
;; Modifies the value of a Dynamic Block property (if present)
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; prp - [str] Dynamic Block property name (case-insensitive)
;; val - [any] New value for property
;; Returns: [any] New value if successful, else nil

(defun LM:setdynpropvalue ( blk prp val )
    (setq prp (strcase prp))
    (vl-some
       '(lambda ( x )
            (if (= prp (strcase (vla-get-propertyname x)))
                (progn
                    (vla-put-value x (vlax-make-variant val (vlax-variant-type (vla-get-value x))))
                    (cond (val) (t))
                )
            )
        )
        (vlax-invoke blk 'getdynamicblockproperties)
    )
)
```

You might call the above functions from the earlier example I provided in the following way (changing the name of the visibility state to suit your block of course):

```lisp
(defun c:test ( / dwg ins )
    (if
        (and
            (setq dwg (getfiled "Select Block" "" "dwg" 16))
            (setq ins (getpoint "\nSpecify insertion point: "))
        )
        (LM:SetVisibilityState
            (vla-insertblock
                (vlax-get-property
                    (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))
                    (if (= 1 (getvar 'cvport))
                        'paperspace
                        'modelspace
                    )
                )
                (vlax-3D-point (trans ins 1 0))
                dwg
                1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
            )
            "YourVisibilityState"
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
(vl-load-com) (princ)
```

---

#### *If the visual preview of the inserted block IS required...*

...Then aside from rolling your own version of the standard `INSERT` command using a `grread` loop (which would also need to imitate all drawing aids, such as [Object Snap](http://lee-mac.com/grsnap.html), and [Orthomode](http://lee-mac.com/orthopoint.html)), you would need to make use of the `INSERT` command.

However, since the visibility state of the block can only be changed *following* the insertion of the block reference, the visual preview displayed to the user will be inaccurate.

To get the best of both worlds, I have previously proposed the following possible solution (along with an accompanying function posted [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/insert-dynamic-block-with-visibility-state-pre-selected/m-p/4714155/highlight/true#M318036)):

```lisp
;; Example demonstrating a method to insert a Dynamic Block with a Visibility State already set.
;; Lee Mac  -  2013-12-24

(defun c:test ( / *error* att blk def doc ent new obj par spc tmp vis )

    (defun *error* ( msg )
        (if (= 'int (type att))
            (setvar 'attreq att)
        )
        (foreach obj (list new def)
            (if (and (= 'vla-object (type obj)) (not (vlax-erased-p obj)))
                (vl-catch-all-apply 'vla-delete (list obj))
            )
        )
        (if (not (wcmatch (strcase msg t) "*break,*cancel*,*exit*"))
            (princ (strcat "\nError: " msg))
        )
        (princ)
    )
    
    (cond
        (   (= 4 (logand 4 (cdr (assoc 70 (tblsearch "layer" (getvar 'clayer))))))
            (princ "\nCurrent layer locked.")
        )
        (   (null (setq blk (getfiled "Select Dynamic Block with Visibility States" "" "dwg" 16)))
            (princ "\n*Cancel*")
        )
        (   (progn
                (setq doc (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))
                      spc (vlax-get-property doc (if (= 1 (getvar 'cvport)) 'paperspace 'modelspace))
                      obj (vlax-invoke spc 'insertblock '(0.0 0.0 0.0) blk 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0)
                )
                (vla-put-visible obj :vlax-false)
                (= :vlax-false (vla-get-isdynamicblock obj))
            )
            (princ "\nSelected block is not dynamic.")
            (vla-delete obj)
        )
        (   (null (setq par (LM:getvisibilityparametername obj)))
            (princ "\nSelected block does not have a visibility parameter.")
            (vla-delete obj)
        )
        (   (null (setq vis (car (LM:listbox "Choose a Visibility State" (acad_strlsort (LM:getdynpropallowedvalues obj par)) 0))))
            (princ "\n*Cancel*")
            (vla-delete obj)
        )
        (   t
            (LM:setdynpropvalue obj par vis)
            (setq tmp 0)
            (while (tblsearch "block" (setq blk (strcat "tmp" (itoa (setq tmp (1+ tmp)))))))
            (vla-put-visible
                (car
                    (vlax-invoke doc
                        'copyobjects
                        (list obj)
                        (setq def (vlax-invoke (vla-get-blocks doc) 'add '(0.0 0.0 0.0) blk))
                    )
                )
                :vlax-true
            )
            (vla-delete obj)
            (setq ent (entlast)
                  att (getvar 'attreq)
            )
            (setvar 'attreq 0)
            (if
                (and
                    (vl-cmdf "_.-insert" blk "_S" 1.0 "_R" 0.0 "\\")
                    (not (eq ent (setq ent (entlast))))
                    (= "AcDbBlockReference" (vla-get-objectname (setq new (vlax-ename->vla-object ent))))
                )
                (progn
                    (vla-explode new)
                    (vla-delete  new)
                )
            )
            (vl-catch-all-apply 'vla-delete (list def))
        )
    )
    (princ)
)

;; Get Visibility Parameter Name  -  Lee Mac
;; Returns the name of the Visibility Parameter of a Dynamic Block (if present)
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; Returns: [str] Name of Visibility Parameter, else nil

(defun LM:getvisibilityparametername ( blk / vis )  
    (if
        (and
            (vlax-property-available-p blk 'effectivename)
            (setq blk
                (vla-item
                    (vla-get-blocks (vla-get-document blk))
                    (vla-get-effectivename blk)
                )
            )
            (= :vlax-true (vla-get-isdynamicblock blk))
            (= :vlax-true (vla-get-hasextensiondictionary blk))
            (setq vis
                (vl-some
                   '(lambda ( pair )
                        (if
                            (and
                                (= 360 (car pair))
                                (= "BLOCKVISIBILITYPARAMETER" (cdr (assoc 0 (entget (cdr pair)))))
                            )
                            (cdr pair)
                        )
                    )
                    (dictsearch
                        (vlax-vla-object->ename (vla-getextensiondictionary blk))
                        "acad_enhancedblock"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        (cdr (assoc 301 (entget vis)))
    )
)

;; Get Dynamic Block Property Allowed Values  -  Lee Mac
;; Returns the allowed values for a specific Dynamic Block property.
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; prp - [str] Dynamic Block property name (case-insensitive)
;; Returns: [lst] List of allowed values for property, else nil if no restrictions

(defun LM:getdynpropallowedvalues ( blk prp )
    (setq prp (strcase prp))
    (vl-some '(lambda ( x ) (if (= prp (strcase (vla-get-propertyname x))) (vlax-get x 'allowedvalues)))
        (vlax-invoke blk 'getdynamicblockproperties)
    )
)

;; Set Dynamic Block Property Value  -  Lee Mac
;; Modifies the value of a Dynamic Block property (if present)
;; blk - [vla] VLA Dynamic Block Reference object
;; prp - [str] Dynamic Block property name (case-insensitive)
;; val - [any] New value for property
;; Returns: [any] New value if successful, else nil

(defun LM:setdynpropvalue ( blk prp val )
    (setq prp (strcase prp))
    (vl-some
       '(lambda ( x )
            (if (= prp (strcase (vla-get-propertyname x)))
                (progn
                    (vla-put-value x (vlax-make-variant val (vlax-variant-type (vla-get-value x))))
                    (cond (val) (t))
                )
            )
        )
        (vlax-invoke blk 'getdynamicblockproperties)
    )
)

;; List Box  -  Lee Mac
;; Displays a DCL list box allowing the user to make a selection from the supplied data.
;; msg - [str] Dialog label
;; lst - [lst] List of strings to display
;; bit - [int] 1=allow multiple; 2=return indexes
;; Returns: [lst] List of selected items/indexes, else nil

(defun LM:listbox ( msg lst bit / dch des tmp rtn )
    (cond
        (   (not
                (and
                    (setq tmp (vl-filename-mktemp nil nil ".dcl"))
                    (setq des (open tmp "w"))
                    (write-line
                        (strcat "listbox:dialog{label=\"" msg "\";spacer;:list_box{key=\"list\";multiple_select="
                            (if (= 1 (logand 1 bit)) "true" "false") ";width=50;height=15;}spacer;ok_cancel;}"
                        )
                        des
                    )
                    (not (close des))
                    (< 0 (setq dch (load_dialog tmp)))
                    (new_dialog "listbox" dch)
                )
            )
            (prompt "\nError Loading List Box Dialog.")
        )
        (   t     
            (start_list "list")
            (foreach itm lst (add_list itm))
            (end_list)
            (setq rtn (set_tile "list" "0"))
            (action_tile "list" "(setq rtn $value)")
            (setq rtn
                (if (= 1 (start_dialog))
                    (if (= 2 (logand 2 bit))
                        (read (strcat "(" rtn ")"))
                        (mapcar '(lambda ( x ) (nth x lst)) (read (strcat "(" rtn ")")))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (if (< 0 dch)
        (unload_dialog dch)
    )
    (if (and tmp (setq tmp (findfile tmp)))
        (vl-file-delete tmp)
    )
    rtn
)
(vl-load-com) (princ)
```

My solution essentially involves temporarily inserting a block reference, configuring the visibility state appropriately, creating a temporary block definition containing the configured dynamic block, and then exploiting the visual preview offered by the standard `INSERT` command to insert the temporary block reference, which is then exploded & purged from the drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Blocks with custom properties are called Dynamic blocks. 
Details and samples You can find [here](http://www.lee-mac.com/dynamicblockfunctions.html)

p.s.
Thank You @LeeMac

Comment: Thank you! I've spent the past few hours trying to solve this and I'm still having a lot of trouble trying to set the Visibility parameter. Can you help guide what I might do next?